# How to tie a date to a relationship in prisma?

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I am trying to make a database with a many-to-many relationship between users and ranks where some ranks can be assigned temporarily. The issue I am having is that I don't know how to tie the timestamp when the rank would expire to the actual rank assigned to a user. This is the model I have worked up (excluding other properties like name, email, etc.):

```
model User {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  ranks         Rank[]
  ...
}

model Rank {
  name        String @id
  users       User[]
  ...
}
```

Any advice is appreciated!

I am not all too experienced with prisma so I didn't have many creative solutions. I thought of making a seperate `model` that replaces the relations and acts as a sort of middle man. I also tried stuff with `types` but that didn't work because of their limitations.

Comment: maybe you can add sometime like rank_expiry, and after fetching looping over array and filtering the expired rank?

Comment: I thought of that as well, but I don't know how to implement this. I can't put it in the rank model because that would apply to all users which I do not want. I can't apply it to the user model because there is an array of ranks and I can't tell how many ranks that user will have and in turn I can't filter out to which rank that would apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor data model, how do you know and enforce that the `users.rank[]` references only those having a corresponding entry in `rank.users[]`. A much better, and common solution to a many:many relationship is to create a resolution table which references both. So something like (I use just Postgres DDL as I do not use prisma or any other orm, but translation should be straight forward.)

```
create table users (
  id          int generated always as identity
                  primary key  
  ... 
);

create table ranks (
  id          int generated always as identity
                  primary key
 ,name        text
  ...
);

-- resolution table 
create table user_rank ( 
  user_id     int  not null 
                   references users(id)
 ,rank_id     int  not null 
                   references ranks(id)
 ,assign_date date not null 
                   default current_date
 ,expiry_date date not null 
                   default '-infinity'::date   
 ,constraint  user_rank_pk
                   primary key (user_id, rank_id) 
);
```

As shown you can now a any intersection data to the resolution table. If you need to maintain the complete history of user_rank just add `assign_date` to the PK.

Comment: I'm sorry if there has been a misunderstanding. Prisma, the library that I am using, automatically generates these tables for you. Raw SQL code is not what I need and it honestly doesn't help solve my problem since I don't know how to implement it in prisma.